# What does "GPU memory" mean in Chrome's Task Manager?

Tags: google-chrome, memory

In the chrome task manager, there is a column called `GPU memory`.

1. What does this memory represent?
2. Is it the memory in physical RAM or in GPU?
3. What's the relationship between GPU memory and memory?

[image: chrome task manager]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. It represents the amount of GPU memory being used by the page. The GPU process is a process used only when Chrome is displaying GPU-accelerated content. Chrome uses GPU to accelerate web-page rendering, typical HTML, CSS, WebGL, etc.
2. The memory is in the GPU of-course.
3. There is no relationship at all. The only governing law is that GPU-accelerated applications use both RAM and GPU memory to achieve faster processing time and also enable power-saving as GPUs consume less power as compared to CPUs. The amount of RAM and GPU that an application will use depends on the code used and the level of parallelism.

**Note:** You can find more information here- http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome

Comment: 2. *"The memory is in the GPU of-course."* Are you sure? Even when Chrome using GPU is switched off, via *"Use hardware acceleration when available > Off"*? In that case is that then CPU or GPU memory?